# Is $X$ reflexive if $X=\cup Y_i $ and $Y_i$ is reflexive for every $i$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Assume that there are a family of closed (with respect to $\left\|\cdot\right\|_X$) subspaces $Y_i$ of $X$ such $X=\cup Y_i $ and $Y_i$ is reflexive for every $i$. Can we say that $X$ is reflexive? (otherwise, under what condition,  $X$ is reflexive).

Comment: Union of subspaces is not  a subspace except in very special circumstances.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Union of one dimensional subsapcaes is not even a vector space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that's not an issue here because we are assuming that $X$ is a banach space and $X=\bigcup\limits_{i}Y_i$. You are right that in general we cannot assume that such an $X$ exists for any union $\bigcup\limits_{i}Y_i$ but here it is assumed implicitly.

Comment: you are right. So, are there any conditions ensure that it is true.

Comment: Almost never. So the question does not make sense at all in the present form.

Comment: It does make sense, it just means that there is only one "true" (i.e. not contained in another $Y_i$) $Y_i$ since that is seemingly the only way to have a Banach space $X$ represented as the union of subspaces. Maybe they meant to write product instead?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  For a reflexive sequence space, there (Calkin) corresponding ideal (on a Hilbert space) is reflexive. So, I am wondering whether there are any general results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (somewhat surprisingly) yes. The reason it's yes is because the assumption $X=\bigcup\limits_{i}Y_i$ is a very strong assumption which greatly reduces which sets $Y_i$ we can consider. Assume that $X = Y_1\cup Y_2$ as a simple example. Then, without loss of generality, $Y_2\subset Y_1$ since otherwise we can take $y_2\in Y_2\backslash Y_1$ and $y_1\in Y_1\backslash Y_2$ to have that $y_1+y_2\in X$ but $y_1+y_2\not\in Y_1\cup Y_2$.

So if $X$ can be written in this way, there must be a "biggest" $Y_k$ which contains all the other $Y_i$. In this case, however, we have that $\bigcup\limits_{i} Y_i = Y_k$ which is reflexive by assumption and so $X=Y_k$ means that $X$ is also reflexive.

Comment: Thx. So, how about the case when X generated by Y_i？Are there any conditions such that it is true？

Comment: It's not obvious to me when it would be true but definitely it's not in general, as we can see by considering the space of sequences.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is too special.

Comment: This answers the question only for FINITE unions! A natural example would be $\ell^p(I)=\bigcup\limits_{J \text{ countable}} \ell^p(J)$ for an uncountable set $I$.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's not clear to me how what you've written at all contradicts my claim that there is a "biggest" subspace.

Answer (score -1):

To make sense out of this question you have to replace the condition $X=\cup_i Y_i$ by the condition that $X$ is the closed subspace generated by reflexive subspaces $Y_i$. But then $X$ need not be reflexive as seen  by considering the collection of all one dimensional subspaces. Of course, there is the trivial case where there is only one $Y_i$ and $X$ is of course, reflexive in that case.

Comment: Thx. So, in the case when X is generated by Y_i. Are there any special case when it is true？

Comment: @user92646 If there are only finite number of $Y_i$'s then $X$ is reflexive. But countably infinite number of  $Y_i$'s won't make $X$ reflexive. For example we can write $C[0,1]$ (or any separable Banach space) in this form.

Comment: Thx！So, I should think over it again.